# An exponential sum formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, exponential-function

It is well known that one can express a finite sum of exponentials as follows:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{inx} = \frac{1-e^{iNx}}{1-e^{ix}}.
$$

Is there a similar formula when the exponential contains a function of $x$? In other words, are there functions $g$ and $h$ such that:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{inx\times f(x)} = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}
$$

In the above expression, $f(x)$ denotes any function on $x$, i.e., $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, $\frac{1}{x}$, $\ldots$

Comment: Why, yes. Just substitute $x\,f(x)$ to $x$ in the above formula.

Comment: But what if $f(x)$ contains a singularity? I.e., $f(x)=x^{-1}$? Then there is an issue...

Comment: Of course there are restrictions, and special cases have to be examined separately. But it's the same for the partial sums of the geometric series: $z$ has to be $\ne 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove the first formula actually for any $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{(1,0)\}$: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} z^n = \frac{1-z^N}{1-z}.$$
Choose $z = e^{if(x)}$ and get your answer.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, what if $f(x)$ contains a singularity? I.e., $f(x)=x^{-1}$?

Comment: In that case just find the domain of $f$. The formula holds as far as $x$ ranges in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, what if $f$ is a function of $n$, i.e., $\sum_0^{N-1}z^{f(n)}$?

Comment: Then the sum is no longer the same in general. For example: if $f(n) = n$ then $\sum_{n=0}^{N} e^{inf(n)} = \sum_{n=0}^{N} e^{in^2} = 1+e^i+e^{4i}+\dots+e^{iN^2}$ and the formula you stated does not hold anymore - yours requires the exponents to be consecutive numbers as in $1+q+q^2+\dots+q^N$.

Comment: There is no general formula for this case then? Is there a methodology to derive one?

Comment: I am not sure about the existence of a general formula for $\sum_{n=0}^N e^{inf(n)}$. I think the method to derive a formula depends on $f$. Do you need this for something more specific?

Comment: No, thank you already for your efforts. I accepted the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has a singularity, then neither the original sum nor the compact expression are defined and... that's it.

I suspect that you are actually thinking of the case that $x f(x)=1$. To get the desired result, you can take the limit to the targeted $x$, provided $x f(x)$ is continuous.